# Not able to receive error in express.js middleware function

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to write an express middleware that handles errors. However, I'm not able to define a function with `err` as an argument. In the express documentation I read the following:

> Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, except error-handling functions have four arguments instead of three: (err, req, res, next)

But when I define the following function, it seems like it's not invoked:

```
myFunction = (config) => {
  return myFunction = (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

module.exports = myFunction
```

The function above isn't invoked when I specify `app.use(myFunction(config))` from my express server, but if I remove the `err` argument it is. Does anyone know why that is the case?

Update: So I got it to work. What I had to do was to specify `pp.use(myFunction(config))` below my routes in my server.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a module `myFunction.js`

```
const myFunction = (err, req, res, next) => {
      console.log(err);
      // do stuff here
};

module.exports = myFunction;
```

In your app.js file, require the module

```
const myFunction  = require('./myFunction');
```

and after your route middleware add this piece of code

```
app.use(myFunction);
```

Comment: I've updated my question above since I forgot to specify that I want to pass in another parameter called `config` to my middleware and therefore I need a wrapping function. Other than that my code looks like yours.

Comment: What parameter do you need to pass? About the error?

Comment: I've stripped away a lot of functionality from `myFunction` to make it simpler to read. The `config` parameter will contain information not related to the error handling functionality.

Comment: It is an Error middleware that catches errors. If you want to add extra functionality depending the error, you could add info on the Error object. Give an example of error to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax error.

Maybe you should do this :

```
const myFunction = (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err);
}
module.exports = myFunction
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the syntax is not the problem since everything works fine if I don't define `err` as an argument and write the following:

`myFunction = () => { return myFunction = (req, res, next) {  console.log('test') }} `
`module.exports = myFunction`